# Compile error using slick MappedColumnType for static query

Tags: scala, slick

I have the following mapper so that I can use Joda DateTime values in my Slick models and queries:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._

object Mappers {
  implicit def joda  =
    MappedColumnType.base[DateTime, Timestamp](
      dt => new Timestamp(dt.getMillis),
      ts => new DateTime(ts.getTime)
    )
}
```

The table classes that I have defined containing a DateTime field appear to compile fine by importing this. However a static query like this will not:

```
sql"""select s.expiresAt from tablename s limit 1""".as[DateTime].first
```

I get this error:

```
  could not find implicit value for parameter rconv: scala.slick.jdbc.GetResult[org.joda.time.DateTime]
```

What do I need to add to make this work?

Comment: Found a solution yet? I'm running into similar problem but with java.time.LocalDate[Time].

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you need to define another converter

```
implicit val getDateTimeResult = GetResult(r => new DateTime(r.nextTimestamp()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in the end by using [slick-joda-mapper](https://github.com/tototoshi/slick-joda-mapper) instead of writing my own mapper.